# Create a field in PBC

Tags: implementation, pairings, group-theory

Edited (I removed the emphasize on Integers):

My question is partly cryptography and partly programming, I would appreciate any help on any aspect of it :)

I want to use [PBC](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/) library to do the following operations:

1. Create a finite group, with "my custom" order ($Z_q$).
2. Choose a random value $g$ from this group.
3. Compute $g^r$, where $r$ is a random integer.

I tried to make the above work but I could not figure out to relate a finite group of my choice to this notion of pairing-based cryptography with no avail!

---

EDIT: Some more info on my problem:

In its simplest form, what I want to do is to choose $g$, $r_1$, and $r_2$, compute $g^{r_1}$ and $g^{r_2}$. To confirm the computation, I will later compute $g^{r_1+r_2}$ and compare it with multiplication of the previous values.

How can I achieve this in PBC?

Comment: The only cryptographic bilinear groups I'm aware of whose elements have a nice representation as integers are the Boneh-Franklin groups ([page 19](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs6204/Privacy-Security/Papers/Crypto/IBE-Weil-Pairing.pdf)). $\:$

Comment: @RickyDemer tnx. Let's forget about integers for a moment Can you tell me what's the deal with this "pairing"? I have read some general description about it, But I cannot relate it to a finite group!

Comment: Isn't the size of ints on your machine a bit small for cryptographic data ?

Comment: @minar Actually int is that important to me. What I meant was sort some sort of type that I can manipulate. Not a struct or ...

Comment: If the group operation is addition, then the pairing is multiplication. $\:$

Comment: I found the function "element_from_hash" which apparently takes an integer as seed and creates an appropriate element. So, my main question, is how to map my problem (described above), to PBC context. Thanks :)

Comment: @Z0lenDer I point this out because a fair number of practicing cryptographers aren't aware: PBC is slow and outdated and a pain to work with. MIRCAL and RELIC are the two main alternatives.

Comment: What you want to do has nothing to do with pairing-based cryptography.  Why would you want to use PBC, or something related to pairings?

Comment: I think I read somewhere that Discrete Log problem can be modelled in Elliptic Curve computation setting. Also, I think PBc is an efficient library that can do elliptic curve computations, so ...

Comment: @imichaelmiers tnx. I go look into them. I remember Relic is still in alpha testing phase, right?

Comment: RELIC is alpha in the sense that you shouldn't use it for production. But it's fine for research.

Comment: @imichaelmiers, Thanks for introducing relic. it actually does what I was looking for and it is pretty straightforward to use it. You can write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Z0lenDer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I point this out because a fair number of practicing cryptographers aren't aware: PBC is slow and outdated and a pain to work with. [MIRCAL](http://www.certivox.com/miracl/) and [RELIC](https://code.google.com/p/relic-toolkit/) are the two main alternatives.

Comment: do you have a link for MIRCAL? The link on the PBC page doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. RELIC actually did what I was looking for and it was very easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any custom order, you need to use one of the predefined parameters (using `pbc_param_init_set_str` or `pbc_param_init_set_buf`) or to generate parameters (but you can't fix a specific order); see the "Param generation" section in the manual.

There is no standard conversion from elements to integers, since in PBC elements are either elliptic curve points or elements in extension fields. You can use `element_to_bytes` and `element_from_bytes` to convert elements to byte arrays, though (which you can interpret as big numbers, if you wish, but doing arithmetic on them will not make sense).

Comment: Thank you. I edit the question to remove the emphasize on Integers. Can you point to a resource or if you describe to me how to map the concept of multiplication in a single group to operations of pairing?

Comment: My question more about this mapping of concepts.